# C function for system("$BASHPID") not working

Tags: c, linux, process

I have a simple program written in C using system() function in Ubuntu 12.04 as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("getpid() = %d\n", getpid());
    printf("getppid() = %d\n", getppid());
    printf("cmd process ID:\n");

    system("echo $BASHPID");
    return 0;
}
```

and ran it using gcc in terminal, which gave the following results.

```
$ gcc -o exmpl_bashpid exmpl_bashpid.c
$ ./exmpl_bashpid 
getpid() = 2892
getppid() = 2060
cmd process ID:

$
```

my question is, the function system("echo $BASHPID") will not give any thing. when I tried with some common commands like date it gives in terminal upon running the executable file. Only this above case is not giving proper results. What can be the possible explanation? I am least known with Linux process and system calls in C programming. Any insight will be helpful for my further exploration. Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? I guess that retrieving `BASHPID`  from a C program is the wrong way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I need to know if system() will really create a different process or not by simply knowing its process id.

Comment: To get the process id of the shell, use `echo $$` which is much more portable and is not `bash` specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` normally runs `/bin/sh` and presumably that does not set `$BASHPID`. Try using:

```
system("/bin/bash -c 'echo $BASHPID'")
```

Note this is always only going to print the PID of the *child* bash process invoked by `system`, which is not very useful. It looks like you are trying to get the PID of the *parent* bash process, which won't work as the parent bash's `BASHPID` variable is not exported, as typing

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo $BASHPID'
```

at the command line will demonstrate.

Comment: If I change the above code as you have suggested, it will give a different PID for each cases. Am I using 3 processes here including shell as one of them? if yes then /bin/bash will make any different process?

Comment: Well, system() starts a new process, so they'll likely get a different pid

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve an environment variable inside a C program, use [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html).

So if you believe that your program is run in an environment when `BASHPID`  is set (i.e. `export` -ed in bash), try:

```
int bashpid = 0;
char*bashpidstr = getenv("BASHPID");
if (bashpidstr && isdigit(bashpidstr[0]))
  bashpid = atoi(bashpidstr);
```

However, quite often the shell is the parent process, which you can query with  [getppid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getppid.2.html). Or it is the process group leader, see [getpgid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpgid.2.html)

If you wish to get the output of some command, use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), e.g.

```
int bashpid = 0;
FILE* cmd = popen("echo $BASHPID", "r");
if (cmd) { fscanf(cmd, "%d", &bashpid); pclose(cmd); }
else { perror("popen"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

But this probably won't work as you want, since `popen`  or `system`  could [fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) a `/bin/sh`  which might be a `bash` ; maybe you should `echo $$`

Also, [BASHPID](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) is specific to `bash`. My interactive (login) shell is [zsh](http://zsh.org/) so won't set it.

Notice that you usually should call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) (e.g. `fflush(NULL);` ...) before any forking function such as `popen` or `system` to ensure stdio buffers are flushed.

#### addenda

If you want to know if [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is creating a different process, read its documentation:

> The system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process
>          that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3)
>          as follows:
>
> ```
>       execl("/bin/sh", "sh". "-c", command, (char *) 0);
> ```
>
> system() returns after the command has been completed.

However, there is a special case if you pass a `NULL` argument to `system`:

> If command is NULL, then system() returns a status indicating whether
>          a shell is available on the system

Also, study the source code of some implementation, e.g. [process/system.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/process/system.c) from [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/)

Comment: BASHPID will not be sent to the C program as it is not exported (as far as I can tell)